# Angular Screenshot Generator

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm building a simple Angular screenshot generator using [this jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Take-A-Snapshot-of-A-Webpage-url2img.html).

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wK2S3Re0VijPmKXEWwXW)

This is my **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <title>Angular Screenshot</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <label>URL:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Insert URL" ng-model="url" autofocus id="urlbox">
            <br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Screenshot" id="submitbtn">
        </form>
        <!-- screenshot -->
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D" data-url="{{url}}">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="url2img.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.submit = function() {
            // I stuck here
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my **url2img.js** file:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('img[data-url]').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=' + $(this).data('url') + '&screenshot=true',
            context: this,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                data = data.screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
                $(this).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data);
            }
        });
    });


});
```

When I open the page, I get this error in my console:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=&screenshot=true 400 (Bad Request)
```

When I hard coded target URL inside the `data-url`, it's working perfectly. But when I put `{{url}}`, the error is showing up.

How to fix this issue and pass the `ng-model="url"` data to the `data-url` only AFTER I click the `Generate Screenshot` button?

Comment: btw, i think google is shutting down that service.

Answer (score 1):

Why use jQuery at all?

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.url) + '&screenshot=true';
    $http.get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
            data = data.screenshot.data.replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/-/g, '+');
            $scope.src =  'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
        });

}
```

And then use `<img ng-src="{{src}} alt="" />`.

Comment: Sergiu: Thanks. I get this error inside my console: ReferenceError: encodeUriComponent is not defined